# Glassfish classloader can't resolve static method of a dependency

Tags: java, classloader, glassfish-3, static-methods

This awful project I know have to put my ands on makes wide (and obnoxious) use of static methods coming from other modules which I now *jarred-out* and declared as dependency of the (now lightweight) webapp.

now glassfish seems to have a problem with that.

it's literally a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError of a certain class that is included in WEB-INF/lib

```
EJB Container initialization error
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class yyy.ohyeah.commons.util.Logger
```

(i'll try to reduce and anonymize the class and put it as a comment)

Here's where the issues arise:

```
import yyy.ohyeah.commons.util.Logger;

@Path("achievement")
@Produces("application/json")
@Stateless
public class MyResource {

    private final static Log log = Logger.getLogger(MyResource.class.getName());
```

Comment: I have all the dependencies needed. this was an ant-built project I'm trying to _mavenize_ . Maven build looks exactly the same as the ant one, but then I have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

you need to include all dependency jars.  In this case, it looks like you need apache commons logging jar.